patent published vs granted
It's my first time to apply for a patent, I know some basic procedures but not very detail, could any expert to clarify my questions below

Could I say my application has no problem from the examiner prospective if the patent office/examiner published it? I know it not guarantee to be granted.

Would the patent office or examiner inform me if they plan to publish my application?

Once it was published, and how long could the patent be granted if there is no objection.


I appreciate if someone could teach me, thanks a lot.


No, usually the examiner has not yet taken a serious look at it.

You get a notice of publication when it publishes (I don't think before). Also note that one can opt to avoid publication with a non-publication request.

You can find some information on average pendency here: https://www.uspto.gov/dashboard/patents/pendency.html



Thank you for the reply and information, it is very helpful and I could arrange my schedule, the time is much longer then I originally think.
I suppose I could check the application status from USPTO website, or just calculate the 18 months from my application date, it will be automatically published as @Eric S said.
I have to re-plan my schedule, and it's really time-consuming. thanks again

You can request early publication. I’m not sure how that would affect your time line and plans.

I am not a lawyer, but I am the inventor on a number of patents. I'll try to explain the process.


Could I say my application has no problem from the examiner prospective if the patent office/examiner published it? I know it not
guarantee to be granted.


US patent applications typically get published 18 months after filing. This is automatic and has nothing to do with the examination process. Publication says nothing about whether a patent will eventually be granted. You should not say or even imply there are no problems with the examiner's prospective. The examiner probably hasn't even read the application yet. All you can say is that the application is filed and a patent is pending. You can say those things as soon as the application if filed. You don't need to wait until publication.


Would the patent office or examiner inform me if they plan to publish my application?


I'm not sure if you are given a heads up. I never was, but perhaps your lawyer might. As I said, publication is automatic.


Once it was published, and how long could the patent be granted if there is no objection.


My experience is that three years after filing the application is about normal assuming everything goes well. It can be a lot longer. I'd like to point out that you are just about guaranteed to have objections from the examiner. This is a normal part of the process. Rejections and even "final rejections" are normal. Weirdly, "final rejections" are usually not final. A good lawyer helps a lot in getting an actual granted patent.

Thank you, Eric,
noted the publication is automatic, and the examiner will only review after publication, I applied for the patent both in UK and USA,  the UK examiner has an Examination Report to me, and asked me to correct my claims, which I made a lot of mistakes, and I submit an amended claims over 3 months ago, there is no more feedback.
could I assume that the application might meet the minimum requirement and will be published accordingly?
I now know I will not be informed and I think I can check the application status if it was published?
have a great day
